# ACL feed for the document

Tags: google-drive-api

Since there is no api to retrieve the ACL feed for a document in Google Drive, I am using Google Document Api to get it done. I tried the protocol method which is mentioned here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#retrieving_the_acl_for_a_document_file_or_collection, but I get an error **Invalid Request URI** even though I am following same method mentioned in the above link with correct access token...Am I missing something??

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace `resource_id` in the URI below with the id of the resource you want to retrieve ACL for:

```
GET https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/resource_id/acl
```

If you are doing so and it still doesn't work, please show us the URI you are using.